# Scrapy: skip classless span with css selectors

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

```
<div class="classA">
   <span class="classB">hello</span>
   <span aria-hidden="true">world</span>
   <span>I want this text</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the text in the 3rd span using CSS selectors. My problem is that I don't know how to skip the second span as it doesn't have a class. Maybe we could use the `aria-hidden="true"`?

So far I have this:

```
response.css('div.classA > span:not([class^="classB"])').get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are always trying to select the 3rd span tag then you can use the nth-child() selector.

```
response.css('div > span:nth-child(3)').get()
```